# Django Group Permissions-like Field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I would like to know how what is the name of the field and how to use it in django admin groups permissions as I attach in the image below. It looks like a ManytoManyField but it is a lot more user freindly.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The given image is a ManyToMany field registered on the admin as `filter_horizontal`

for an Author model described below,

```
class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

You can make the author like what shown in the image by registering it as

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ('authors',)

admin.site.register(Book, BookAdmin)
```

**`filter_horizontal = ('authors',)`** on the BookAdmin will create the author as shown below.

[image]